# How do I link glibc's implementation of iconv?

Tags: c, linux, linker, glibc, iconv

The GNU C library provides an implementation of iconv - how do I use it?

Simple program:

```
#include <iconv.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv ) {
        iconv_t cd = iconv_open( "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1" );
        iconv_close( cd );
        return 0;
}
```

Compile and link:

```
$ gcc -Wall iconv.c -o iconv
/tmp/ccKAfXNg.o: In function `main':
iconv.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
iconv.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `libiconv_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

List the symbols to show they exist!

```
$ nm -D /lib/libc-2.12.1.so | grep iconv
00017920 T iconv
00017ae0 T iconv_close
00017720 T iconv_open
```

If I install the GNU libiconv library to /usr/local and link with -liconv it works. How do I link with the glibc implementation of iconv?

EDIT: More information as requested from the comments:

List all iconv.h files in /usr (1 match)

```
$ find /usr/ | grep "iconv\.h"
/usr/include/iconv.h
```

Reinstall libc6-dev to ensure the correct header is installed.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/iconv.h 
libc6-dev: /usr/include/iconv.h
$ apt-get install --reinstall libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Building dependency tree                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Reading state information... Done                                                                                                                                                                                                              
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.                                                                                                                                                                  
Need to get 0B/4,910kB of archives.                                                                                                                                                                                                            
After this operation, 0B of additional disk space will be used.                                                                                                                                                                                
(Reading database ... 143458 files and directories currently installed.)                                                                                                                                                                       
Preparing to replace libc6-dev 2.12.1-0ubuntu10.1 (using .../libc6-dev_2.12.1-0ubuntu10.1_i386.deb) ...                                                                                                                                        
Unpacking replacement libc6-dev ...                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Setting up libc6-dev (2.12.1-0ubuntu10.1) ...
```

Compile and link again with suggested preprocessor option:

```
$ gcc -Wall -DLIBICONV_PLUG iconv.c -o iconv
/tmp/ccKAfXNg.o: In function `main':
iconv.c:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
iconv.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `libiconv_close'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Output from gcc -H:

```
$ gcc -H iconv.c 
. /usr/include/iconv.h
.. /usr/include/features.h
... /usr/include/bits/predefs.h
... /usr/include/sys/cdefs.h
.... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
... /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h
.... /usr/include/bits/wordsize.h
.... /usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h
.. /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include/stddef.h
Multiple include guards may be useful for:
/usr/include/bits/predefs.h
/usr/include/gnu/stubs-32.h
/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.4.5/include/stddef.h
```

[pastbin copy of /usr/include/iconv.h](http://pastebin.com/iQC1sBZq)

Fixed: Reboot fixed the issue. I suspect a cached copy of libiconv was causing the conflicts, even though it was deleted from disk.

Comment: Can you provide the contents of /usr/include/iconv.h in a pastebin?

Comment: `iconv.h` is fine. But I just noticed something weird. In both failed gcc runs, the name of the temporary file (`/tmp/ccKAfXNg.o`) is the same! It is supposed to be random! It seems as if your linker is picking up stale files...

Comment: Though I *did* try the requested pre-processor define, it didn't work, and as error itself was the same as the first error, I copy/pasted the output from the first failed compile... lesson learnt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your program seems fine and compiles fine on my system (Mandriva Linux 2010.1).

I find the `libiconv_*` references in your compile log worrisome, though. Are you sure that the `iconv.h` version that gets included comes from glibc and not from a separate libiconv implementation, such as GNU libiconv? It sounds as if it adds a `lib` prefix to all iconv functions to avoid symbol collisions with the iconv implementation of the C library that came with the system.

Having to explicitly link to libiconv points to a separate iconv implementation too - glibc does not need it.

EDIT:

For the record, I just verified that using the `iconv.h` header file from libiconv without explicitly linking against it will produce exactly the result that you are seeing - it renames all iconv functions by adding a `lib` prefix to their names.

Comment: I did install libiconv to /usr/local to test it, but have since removed it with a 'make uninstall' - no traces left that I can see.

Comment: @DrTwox: can you _verify_ which iconv.h gets included?

Comment: @DrTwox you can perform the verification by making use of the `-H` option to gcc. It will print the path of the files included.

Comment: @DrTwox: Does adding `-DLIBICONV_PLUG` to your compiler options fix it without `-liconv`? If it does, then you are using the `iconv.h` version from libiconv.

Comment: The computer froze, I reset, it worked. I still don't know what the problem was. Though I uninstalled libiconv from /usr/local, and confirmed it was all deleted, all clues point to the system still seeing the wrong header - stale cache perhaps? I don't understand the deep-down magic of Linux to figure it out myself.