# Binding with libiconv failed while compiling R-devel on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I have been spending one day to try to compile R-devel.
I have used this [post](http://singmann.org/installing-r-devel-on-linux/) to do so.

Regardless of what I do, I have:

```
[...]/src/main/sysutils.c:794: undefined reference to `libiconv'
[...]
[...]/src/main/platform.c:3052: undefined reference to `u_getVersion_54'
[...]
```

add many other similar lines, similar to the last comment of [this post](http://jtremblay.github.io/software_installation/2017/06/21/Install-R-3.4.0-and-RStudio-on-Ubuntu-16.04).

Obviously, I have:

```
$ sudo apt install libc6-dev
libc6-dev is already the newest version (2.24-9ubuntu2.2).
```

The configuration step regarding libiconv seems ok:

```
checking iconv.h usability... yes
checking iconv.h presence... yes
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for iconv... yes
checking whether iconv accepts "UTF-8", "latin1", "ASCII" and "UCS-*"... yes
checking for iconvlist... no
checking for iconv... yes
checking for iconv declaration...
     extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);
```

The command `iconv -l` seems to work fine.  The C file described in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709178/how-do-i-link-glibcs-implementation-of-iconv) compiles with no problem either.

Where should I look?  I use Gnome Ubuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 1):

Well, well, well: I have been doing for probably a decade or more and there are some older posts of mine floating. In fact, the blog post you use references my script via a five-year old email -- these still work for me.

My current version is attached below. I have been building this all these years on "whatever is the current Ubuntu version", with a slight upgrade delay.  So like you I am currently on 17.04, and I just use `libicu-dev` which gets we the `libicu57` runtime.

That said, you also get r-devel "prebuilt" via Docker images from our Rocker project.  This this [recent arXiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.03675) descrining the project, and mentioning `r-devel` and `drd`, both available from [hub.docker.com](http://hub.docker.com).

My script follows.  There is no magic in. You may need to remove the `ccache` or install `ccache`.

```
#!/bin/sh

cd ~/svn/r-devel

R_PAPERSIZE=letter              \
R_BATCHSAVE="--no-save --no-restore"        \
R_BROWSER=xdg-open              \
PAGER=/usr/bin/pager                \
PERL=/usr/bin/perl              \
R_UNZIPCMD=/usr/bin/unzip           \
R_ZIPCMD=/usr/bin/zip               \
R_PRINTCMD=/usr/bin/lpr             \
LIBnn=lib                   \
AWK=/usr/bin/awk                                \
CC="ccache gcc"                 \
CFLAGS="-ggdb -pipe -std=gnu99 -Wall -pedantic" \
CXX="ccache g++"                \
CXXFLAGS="-ggdb -pipe -Wall -pedantic"      \
FC="ccache gfortran"                \
F77="ccache gfortran"               \
MAKE="make -j4"                 \
./configure                     \
    --prefix=/usr/local/lib/R-devel         \
    --enable-R-shlib                \
    --without-blas              \
    --without-lapack                \
    --without-recommended-packages

make 

echo "*** Done -- now run 'make install'"
```

And for what it is worth I get the *exact same iconv message* which appears to be just informative:

```
checking iconv.h usability... yes                                                                                                                                                                                  checking iconv.h presence... yes                                                                                                                                                                                   
checking for iconv.h... yes                                                                                                                                                                                        checking for iconv... yes                                                                                                                                                                                          
checking whether iconv accepts "UTF-8", "latin1", "ASCII" and "UCS-*"... yes                                                                                                                                       checking for iconvlist... no                                                                                                                                                                                       
checking for iconv... yes                                                                                                                                                                                          checking for iconv declaration...                                                                                                                                                                                  
         extern size_t iconv (iconv_t cd, char * *inbuf, size_t *inbytesleft, char * *outbuf, size_t *outbytesleft);                                                                                               checking wchar.h usability... yes                                                                                                                                                                                  
checking wchar.h presence... yes
```

Your problem, then, seems to be that you lack `libiconv-dev`, and presumably *many more* such `-dev` packages: it is not just `libc6-dev`.

*Edit:* Come to think about it, the aforementioned Dockerfiles are probably a good proxy for the packages you need.  See eg [here](https://github.com/rocker-org/drd/blob/601c703fdf2373a06706b78cf7863f8305956f79/Dockerfile#L19-L62) for the corresponding 43 lines (!!) from drd.

Comment: It seems that there is no such `libiconv-dev` package? The command `$ sudo apt install libiconv-dev` gives `E: Unable to locate package libiconv-dev`, which confirms [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898826/why-is-there-no-libiconv-package-in-ubuntu).  Will try the Docker solution, though.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about / mixing up `libcu` and `libiconv`.  Iconc does indeed come with libc6 methinks.  But your problem is fundamentally the same: lack of Depends.

Comment: Well, beats me, but I can assure you that I have been building R itself on Debian for 20+ years (and maintaining it for most of these).  It works.  You likely have an earlier error, or you mix i386 and amd64 libraries, or ...

Comment: Most likely true, but I do not where... and I did install R devel ~ 2 months ago, with no problem. D'oh!

Comment: You can come to the `r-sig-debian` mailing list we have for Debian and Ubuntu and folks can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Gotcha!

The problem was a conflict with Conda.
Removing the Conda directory solved the problem.